# MogoDb connection with Django

Tags: django, mongodb, connection

I am having issue with database connection with MongoDB.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '‘djongo’',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'DJANGOPROJECT'),
        'HOST' : 'mongodb+srv://rshah2:******@cluster0.nwaeb.mongodb.net/DJANGOPROJECT?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        'USER' : 'rshah2',
        'PASSWORD' : '*****',
        
    }
}
```

But, when I try to run code, I get an error

```
raise InvalidName("database names cannot contain the "
pymongo.errors.InvalidName: database names cannot contain the character '\\'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to give path in `NAME`. just use the DB Name there.

**Try this :**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '‘djongo’',
        'NAME': 'DJANGOPROJECT',
        'HOST' : 'mongodb+srv://rshah2:******@cluster0.nwaeb.mongodb.net/DJANGOPROJECT?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        'USER' : 'rshah2',
        'PASSWORD' : '*****',
        
    }
}
```

Comment: its only Name. There is a problem in  'HOST', not in name.

Comment: But you error says `raise InvalidName("database names cannot contain the "
pymongo.errors.InvalidName: database names cannot contain the character '\\'`. It clearly says `Name`